# antd PageHeader styles not loading in my React component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I was trying to use ant design but somehow the styles are not loading. I have imported the css in my root component also. But still, I see no styling.

I am using [PageHeader](https://ant.design/components/page-header/) component from antd. I don't seem to understand what might be the problem here. Need some help!

**Header.js**

```js
import React from "react"
import { PageHeader, Button, Descriptions } from "antd"
import "../styles/header.css"

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className="site-page-header-ghost-wrapper">
      <PageHeader
        ghost={false}
        onBack={() => window.history.back()}
        title="Title"
        subTitle="This is a subtitle"
        extra={[
          <Button key="3">Operation</Button>,
          <Button key="2">Operation</Button>,
          <Button key="1" type="primary">
            Primary
          </Button>,
        ]}
      >
        <Descriptions size="small" column={3}>
          <Descriptions.Item label="Created">Lili Qu</Descriptions.Item>
          <Descriptions.Item label="Association">
            <a>421421</a>
          </Descriptions.Item>
          <Descriptions.Item label="Creation Time">
            2017-01-10
          </Descriptions.Item>
          <Descriptions.Item label="Effective Time">
            2017-10-10
          </Descriptions.Item>
          <Descriptions.Item label="Remarks">
            Gonghu Road, Xihu District, Hangzhou, Zhejiang, China
          </Descriptions.Item>
        </Descriptions>
      </PageHeader>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

**styles/header.css**

```js
.site-page-header-ghost-wrapper {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 24px;
}
```

**index.js**

```js
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import App from "./containers/App"
import "antd/dist/antd.css";


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
/* eslint-disable */
var webpack = require("webpack")
var path = require("path")
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  entry: "./client/index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: { loader: "babel-loader" },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
          },
          { loader: "sass-loader" },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {},
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist/bundle/",
    publicPath: "/static/",
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development"),
      },
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "bundle.css",
    }),
  ],
}
```

Comment: did you install the antd or imported the styles?

Comment: yes @godfather.